# Merge TFVC repository into existing TFVC repo

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I'm working on migrating a team project from an on-premise TFS server into an existing Team Project on VSTS. Both Team Projects use Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) as its source control system.

First I looked into Microsofts [TfsMigrator tool](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/migrate-tfs-vsts/), but this require me to create a new VSTS account. Then I've been looking into [VSTS Sync Migrator](http://vsts-bulk-editor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#vsts-sync-migration-tools-faq) which will allow me to transfer work items, but not source code history.

So I'm now wondering:

Is there any way of migrating the source code to the existing TFVC repository without losing history?

Alternatively, can we create a new Team Project in VSTS and move the source code there, and still keep the history?

Been trying both, but can't figure out a way. Google only want me to migrate to Git, which is not what I want.

Comment: This blogpost sort of answered my question: https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2017/05/10/options-migrating-tfs-to-vsts/, It says: "Look at 3rd party tools, maybe moving code via Git TFS or using tools like Timely Migrations, or as a final resort TFS Integration Platform"

Comment: Since your question has been answered, you can add the steps in a answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to create a new GIT repository in our Team Project, and then migrate our code there using [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md).

An alternative would be to use [OpsHub](https://www.opshub.com/), but that would require a new Team Project.